# Parts and tocloft compatibility

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, parts

Whenever I try using both `tocloft` (to be more precise `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` and `\part{}`, the table of contents doesn't render completely (it only renders until the first Part starts).

My question is simple: is there any way to make Parts compatible with `tocloft`, or any other way to show my document-defined typeface on the TOC without using the `tocloft` package, so that the Parts don't enter in conflict with `tocloft` iself?

A sample document that shows this incompatibilty:

```
%--------------------------------------------------------
%    PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%--------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=13pt, twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand\partheadstartvskip{\clearpage\null\vfil} 
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{\par\nobreak\vskip 20pt\thispagestyle{empty}}
\renewcommand\partheadendvskip{\vfil\clearpage}
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}

%--------------------------------------------------------
%    DOCUMENT
%--------------------------------------------------------
\title{\normalfont Title}
\author{Author}
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\part{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor}
\section{Sit}
\part{Amet}

\end{document}
```

If I don't use the `tocloft` package, I get all the sections on the TOC. But If I do use it, the TOC stops rendering after the first `\part`; the document renders perfectly, though.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a minimal working example illustrating the mentioned problem?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I hope the example I've just added helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps; thanks for adding it. You code has some problems: `sectsty` and `scrartcl` seem to be incompatible and also `tocloft` and `scrartcl`; for the first package, the KOMA classes offer their own commands to customize the headings for the sectional units; for the second problem, instead of `tocloft`, you must use the `tocstyle` package which was specifically written for the KOMA classes.

Comment: Ok, I'll try your suggestions and investigate further about the packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gonzalo Medina's comment I came up with the problem on my code.

First, [`sectsty` documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/sectsty.pdf) states that KOMA classes are compatible with the package, so no problem here.

The actual problem was `tocloft`. I replaced

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

with

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
```

and everything works as a charm.

(I use the `standard` option because it uses default-defined typeface (lmodern in my case), instead of using Sans Serif fonts for parts and sections and using serif fonts for the subsections [this can be done in `tocstyle` by using `classic` instead of `standard`] ).

**Apparently, [`tocloft`](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) is not fully compatible with KOMA-Script classes, so using `tocstyle`, which is specially designed to be used in KOMA-Script classes is the best option.**