# How to make a table of contents listing PDFs not generated by the same TeX file?

Tags: table-of-contents

Given that there are, say five papers taking 30 pages of PDFs WITHOUT source TeX files, how do I make a table of contents to list each of them by LaTeX? Moreover, how to assign page numbers to each included PDFs?

Comment: You can always add stuff to the toc using `addcontensline` and it's related commands.

Answer (score 2):

Use the package tocloft then add `\tableofcontents` to wherever you want the table of contents to appear in the master doc.

To add a section to your table of contents, if they are not picked up automatically, you can use the code below. Just add it below each section heading you wish to appear in your table of contents, replacing section_name for the section heading.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{\protect\numberline{}section_name}
```

Chapter can be substituted for another section type such as section or subsection to define the level it appears in the table of contents.

If you don't have well defined sections then using something like

```
\clearpage
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{section_name}
```

will provide an anchor point for the table of contents and add section_name for a reference point to table of contents.

Comment: Can you elaborate why package `tocloft` should be loaded? It leads to some incompatibilities with KOMA-script.

Comment: It just provides additional functionality but is not essential. What are the incompatibilities it causes?

Comment: KOMA comes with package tocstyle to style the appearance of the toc. [tocloft, listoffigures, listof=totoc, KOMA: not in tableofcontents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123230) and [Parts and tocloft compatibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112027)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. However, I do not understand the proposal. My question is: Given that there are, say 30 pages of PDF without source file, how do I make a table of contents of them by LaTeX?

Comment: @Comeseeconquer Well, explain yourself, sir. Is this *one* pdf document with different sections? Or is every pdf-document a section of its own?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thank you for your interest. I am sorry for confusing you, if willing please see the edited version.

Comment: As James suggested: `\cleapage\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title of your pdf tat gets printed to the toc}\includepdf{pdfname.pdf}` This is for documents without chapters. Dunno, what you are using.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more verbose to get a verbose solution/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `pdfpages` to include the PDFs, and include a sectioning or add-to-contents command in the `pagecommand` option of the `\includepdf` command.

For example, assuming you have a base `.tex` file and two PDFs to attach in a `pdfs` subdirectory. (Be sure to compile twice.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Main Text}

Two attachments follow. % I show two different ways below.

% (1) With a section command in the main file 
% (the heading will be printed on a separate page, 
%  but will not overlap with inserted PDF content)

\clearpage\section{First Attachment}
\includepdf[pages=-]{pdfs/doc1} % pages=- means all pages

% (2) With a pagecommand (heading will be printed ON 
% the inserted PDF, so may overlap with content)

\includepdf[pages=1, pagecommand={\section{Second Attachment}}]{pdfs/doc2}
\includepdf[pages=2-last]{pdfs/doc2}

\end{document}
```

---

PDF 1 (compile from pdfs/doc1.tex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-19]
\end{document}
```

---

PDF 2 (compile from pdfs/doc2.tex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[20-29]
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: What to do with standalone pdf-documents coming with their own title?

Comment: You could manually add them to the contents as the other answer shows, or just repeat the title in the section command (like a cover page for each attachment).

Comment: @Johannes_B I see you have just suggested something similar.

Comment: Pardon me, would you mind showing me an output?

Comment: @Comeseeconquer I edited to show the first page; also I added a `\clearpage` before the first PDF heading so that the title appears on its own page as a cover page before the attached PDF (in the first method described).

Comment: Why there is no page number showed?